# angular-ui-select with empty <option> shows 2 empty fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select

I am using `angular-ui-select` for dropdowns. I need to have dropdown that you can cancel.

Here is my dropdown in template:

```
<select ui-select2="select2Options" name="Machine" ng-model="selectedMachine.type" data-placeholder="type" required>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="type in machineTypes" value="{{type}}">{{type}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is `select2Options`:

```
$rootScope.select2Options = {
  minimumResultsForSearch: 5,
  allowClear: true,
  ...
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]
[image]

As you can see, there is a cancel button (and it works), but something weird happens on the picture to the left. **Cause of the `<option value=""></option>` there are two empty fields that you can check.**

If you delete `<option value=""></option>`, weird empty fields disappear, however there is no cancel button either:
[image]

**What should I do to have a cancel button and don't have empty fields?**

*angular: v1.4.8

angular-ui-select2: v0.0.5

select2: v3.4*

Comment: have you tried it with `ngOptions`? It's adding empty option when model is not selected to prevent from false data

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <select ui-select2="select2Options" name="Machine" ng-model="selectedMachine.type" data-placeholder="type" required>

<option value="" selected="selected">Select Machine</option>
<option ng-repeat="type in machineTypes" value="{{type}}">{{type}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It definitely throws an error if you not select any items.

Comment: it doesn't fix anything. I still have one extra empty field and no X button.

Answer (score 0):

I know is a really bad hack, but in my case I could not update "angular-ui" to its latest version.

1. go to **angular-ui.js**
2. find **angular.module('ui.select2'**
3. change "**priority: 1**" to **priority: 1001**

Apparently in newer versions of AngularJs, the priority of ng-repeat was increased to 1000, so it modifies the DOM before the "select2" directive sets up its watchers.

By increasing its *priority*, when the ng-repeat adds 'options' to the DOM the select2 is already watching.

Answer (score -1):

your code maybe like this:

```
<select ui-select2="select2Options" name="Machine" ng-model="selectedMachine.type" data-placeholder="type" ng-options="item.type for item in machineTypes" required>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah, but there is now another problem, when you click on some item, it saved data to modal, but doesn't show that this item is selected. It only does if you click on some item twice